# Static NSMutableDictionary is "just leaking"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

Here's a simple class:

```
#import "One.h"
#import "Two.h"

@implementation DataFileRegistrar

static NSMutableDictionary *elementToClassMapping;

+ (void)load
{
    [self registerClass:[One class] forElement:@"one"];
    [self registerClass:[Two class] forElement:@"two"];
}

+ (void)registerClass:(Class)class forElement:(NSString *)element
{
    if (!elementToClassMapping) {
        elementToClassMapping = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:class forKey:element];
    } else {
        [elementToClassMapping setValue:class forKey:element];
    }
}

+ (id)classForElement:(NSString *)element
{
    return [elementToClassMapping valueForKey:element];
}

@end
```

The problem is this compiler message:

`objc[7172]: Object 0x6840720 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug`

Any ideas what's going on?

Basically, I want to have a simple class with a couple of class methods and one static dictionary. It would be always used without instantiation. I want to use it for a couple of things right after the app starts and then I want to release its memory. I thought ARC can take care of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class' `+load` is calling methods which calls `autorelease`.

Your class is loaded before `main`.

You can explicitly create an autorelease pool in `+load`:

```
+ (void)load
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [self registerClass:[One class] forElement:@"one"];
        [self registerClass:[Two class] forElement:@"two"];
    }
}
```

However, it's often better to guarantee the order of your program's initialization and load explicitly before creating any threads in `main`:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
      [DataFileRegistrar initializeStaticStuff];
      ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not use autoreleased objects on static variables.

Change line...

```
 elementToClassMapping = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:class forKey:element];
```

to

```
 elementToClassMapping = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:class] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:element]];
```

And also do not call your `+ (void)registerClass:(Class)class forElement:(NSString *)element` from a 2nd thread without creating a autorelease pool.

Comment: Autoreleased objects are fine;  but unretained autorelease objects are not. :)   You can still use `dictionaryWithObject:forKey:; it simply needs to be retained.

Comment: Your right. But when i'd like to avoid autorelease i do it right :) . It's more for a better code reading later.

Comment: BTW:  You're suggested re-write uses two autoreleased objects [the NSArray instances]....

Comment: Stylistically I'd prefer continuing to use dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys and retaining it, as bbum said, but my compiler kept showing the error until I changed to initWithObjectsAndKeys as Jonas showed.

Answer (score -1):

what are you doing there is putting the dictionary on the stack (which is frankly stupid, because you have so many ways not to do that) and it leaks because it never gets deallocated  from the stack.

NSDictionary is created to be used with autorelease pool (and yes..i know there are some cases where is better to use a static one but those cases are very very rare )

declare `NSMutableDictionary *elementToClassMapping;` in interface and everything will work just fine

Comment: This has nothing to do with the stack.  The analysis is incorrect and the recommended fix is incorrect.